# ThirdWeb:- Failed to get upload token

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, npx, hardhat, thirdweb

I got this error while npx thirdweb@0.9.13 deploy
and when i install npx thirdweb@latest create --contract then also it give my some error
now please help me how I can solve this problem I tried everything but not able to find the solution

```
✔ Detected project type: hardhat
✔ Compilation successful
✔ Processing contract: "CrowdFunding"
✖ Error uploading metadata

 Error  Failed to get upload token
error stack:
• thirdweb-dev-storage.cjs.prod.js:365 getUploadToken
    C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\42aeb50a0940685c\node_modules\storage\dist\thirdweb-dev-storage.cjs.prod.js:365:13

• task_queues:95 processTicksAndRejections
    node:internal\process\task_queues:95:5

• thirdweb-dev-storage.cjs.prod.js:514 uploadBatchNode
    C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\42aeb50a0940685c\node_modules\storage\dist\thirdweb-dev-storage.cjs.prod.js:514:19

• thirdweb-dev-storage.cjs.prod.js:694 uploadBatch
    C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\42aeb50a0940685c\node_modules\storage\dist\thirdweb-dev-storage.cjs.prod.js:694:14

• thirdweb-dev-storage.cjs.prod.js:655 upload
    C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\42aeb50a0940685c\node_modules\storage\dist\thirdweb-dev-storage.cjs.prod.js:655:19

• processor.ts:191 <anonymous>
    C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\42aeb50a0940685c\node_modules\thirdweb\src\common\processor.ts:191:22

• processor.ts:185 c1
    C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\42aeb50a0940685c\node_modules\thirdweb\src\common\processor.ts:185:11

• index.ts:47 M2
    C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\42aeb50a0940685c\node_modules\thirdweb\src\deploy\index.ts:47:15

• index.ts:122 <anonymous>
    C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\42aeb50a0940685c\node_modules\thirdweb\src\cli\index.ts:122:19


PS E:\TUTORIALS-web\PROJECT\blockchain\crowd-funding\web3>
```

this is my hardhat.config.js

```
require("@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-solc");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  zksolc: {
    version: "1.3.9",
    compilerSource: "binary",
    defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
    networks: {
      hardhat: {},
      sepolia: {
        url: "https://rpc.ankr.com/eth_sepolia",
        accounts: [`0x${process.env.PRIVATE_KEY}`],
      },
    },
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
      },
    },
  },
  networks: {
    zksync_testnet: {
      url: "https://zksync2-testnet.zksync.dev",
      ethNetwork: "goerli",
      chainId: 280,
      zksync: true,
    },
    zksync_mainnet: {
      url: "https://zksync2-mainnet.zksync.io/",
      ethNetwork: "mainnet",
      chainId: 324,
      zksync: true,
    },
  },
  paths: {
    artifacts: "./artifacts-zk",
    cache: "./cache-zk",
    sources: "./contracts",
    tests: "./test",
  },
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.17",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I want that it deploy successfully and thirdweb dashboard link are shown

Answer (score 0):

You're using the older version and the older command to create your contract via the CLI, Here's the latest version and command you should use:

```
npx thirdweb create contract
```

Also with the latest version you need to get an API key and enter into the CLI as shown in the thirdweb docs here:

https://portal.thirdweb.com/api-keys